# Java Selenium Authentication Issue

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am currently trying to use the most recent version of Selenium to automate the login authentication process for a website. At the time when I run the code it doesn't seem to fill any thing out.

```
package browserTest;

import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.security.UserAndPassword;

public class browserRunThrough 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        WebDriver driver1 = new FirefoxDriver();

        driver1.get("URL");

        Alert alert = driver1.switchTo().alert();
        alert.authenticateUsing(new UserAndPassword("username","password"));

    }
}
```

EDIT: by not fill anything thing out I mean I get to the url but it doesn't fill out the username or password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add WebDriverWait :

```
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
 Alert alert = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
 alert.authenticateUsing(new UserAndPassword("username","password"));
```

Also you can use [autoit](http://learn-automation.com/handle-windows-authentication-using-selenium-webdriver/).

Answer (score -1):

Please check that the firefox vesion matches with the selenium webdriver version.
Also please make sure that you have correctly configured the settings of firefox.